# Параллельное выполнение async-функций в Питоне

Tags: python, асинхронность

Есть функция, определенная как async:

```
async def doStuff()
```

Необходимо таких функций вызвать много и параллельно. Пробую так:

```
with futures.ProcessPoolExecutor as pool:
        running = [await pool.submit(doStuff,arg1),await pool.submit(doStuff,arg2)]
        while running:
            done,running = futures.wait(running,timeout=30,return_when=ALL_COMPLETED)
            for future in done:
                session = future.result()
                print(session)
```

Однако, получаю ошибку

```
with futures.ProcessPoolExecutor as pool:
AttributeError: __enter__
```

Нельзя использовать async-функции в экзекьюторе?

Answer (score 0):

Во-первых

```
with futures.ProcessPoolExecutor() as pool:
```

Во-вторых, сопрограмму надо запускать в цикле событий

```
async def do_async_stuff():
    ...

def do_stuff():
    asyncio.run(do_async_stuff())
```

*Пример не самый удачный, только для демонстрации принципа.*

В-третьих, зачем вам вообще `ProcessPoolExecutor`? Почему не просто

```
args = [arg1, arg2]
loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.run_until_complete(asyncio.wait([doStuff(arg) for arg in args]))
```

Comment: Как тогда в этом случае получить результаты от выполнения doStuff()? Они мне нужны потом для выполнения другой операции. Я В случае двух аргументов мне надо дождаться получения обоих результатов, но когда экземпляров будет > 2, надо дождаться хотя бы два, а затем "подключать" каждый последующий.

Comment: Использовать [gather](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.gather) вместо `wait`.